# Mavic - TIME ATAC pedals compatibility

Tags: pedals, pedals-clipless

I'm using from a long time TIME pedals (ATAC).
I saw that Mavic now is making pedals that looks like Time's.

Do you know if they are compatible?
Can I use cleats from Time (already on my shoes :) with pedals made by Mavic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mavic pedals are [ATAC](http://www.mavic.us/pedals/atac) (see also the [cleat page](http://www.mavic.com/pedals-accessories-mtb-atac-cleat#.VEZORYvZ1BM)). They were [developed by TIME](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/mavic-crossmax-xt-pedal-review-2014.html) and just [rebranded by Mavic](http://www.cxmagazine.com/mavic-crossmax-sl-pedal-fury-shoe-product-review).

So, I'd expect that they're compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I can't upvote (I need 15 points to do that!)